# Controller not working on RWBY: Grimm Eclipse

Tags: rwby-grimm-eclipse

I am using a Logitech Chillstream, which uses XInput drivers as any Xbox (or Xbox style) controller. However, only the left thumb stick works in-game. The store page claims that the game has full controller support. My controller is basically an Xbox controller with a fan, I've used it on an Xbox and it works perfectly and I've never encountered a game that would only recognize analog input and not button inputs. Since it's an early-access game I can understand some problems, but I'm not sure if it's a problem with the controller or the game has weird controller support. Is there any information on controller support or a fix, which will allow me to use my controller?

Comment: Does the controller work fine in other games?

Comment: Yes, every game I've played. Never encountered a problem with it.

Comment: Might be worth checking on the steam forum discussions for this game if it's a known issue or not.  Might be an issue with the game or a bug worth reporting.

Comment: That's the place I checked first and the only answer I could find is "Just button mash and it, sometimes, works." People are using different controllers so it is, obviously, a problem with the game. I was just wondering if there is a possible fix.